# How do I prepare exterior concrete walls for painting?

Tags: walls, masonry, cement

My house exterior walls are cement - how do I prep it before painting? Here's some photos. I'm thinking maybe a pressure washer but would prefer an easier, less messy alternative if available. I read up on some websites but the info conflicted. But I did read about using KRUD KUTTER KK32 instead of trisodium phosphate??? My goal is to do it right, do it once so it will last as long as possible. I'm thinking of using KRUD KUTTER KK32 to be neighbor friendly (due to over-spray???)

- Do I power wash the paint off, then use the KRUD KUTTER KK32 and then paint or can I skip the KRUD KUTTER KK32?
- any technique for catching the paint to make cleanup easier?
- What paint type is best to use (for a flat finish - white or brown; not sure yet). I've read about using enamel, oil and latex

Please advise

[image: photo 1]

[image: photo 2]

Answer (score 1):

If by cement you mean stucco (which is essentially cement) you need to strip off the layer of paint that is peeling. That's typically done with sandblasting--but not using sand as an aggregate. They typically use a softer material like the husks of nuts.

You then need to paint with a proper stucco paint that will breathe.

It's not a simple job, unfortunately.

The DIY method would be using a lot of elbow grease and manually scraping as much of the flaking paint off that you can with wire brushes.

Answer (score 0):

The concrete should be etched and a paint specifically made for exterior concrete used. [Sherwin-Williams](http://www.sherwin-williams.com/home-builders/products/catalog/shelf/interior-paint-coatings/masonry-concrete-products/concrete-preparation-products/) has specialty acrylics for concrete and etching solutions as do other leading manufacturers.

Either of those cleaners containing phosphorus, will clean and remove oils. Etching opens pores in the concrete providing something to bond to and removes the alkali salts that will prevent good adhesion. Use tarps to keep the mess manageable.

Pressure washing sounds like an easy way to get most of it, but I'd still use physical means (scraping, sanding) to finish it up. The red chimney is cute. Consider that this two-tone is keeping your house from looking boring and bland.

Answer (score -3):

There are several stuffs you can do to your exterior painting job, as well as help keep the paint look new for longer. See these top 10 ways you can do your paintwork and protect it over time.

1. Ensure That Exterior Surfaces Are Fully Inspected Before Painting.
2. Check The Exterior Walls And Surfaces For Signs Of Weather Damage.
3. Prep The Surface Walls Before Painting With High Quality Tools And Equipment
4. Apply a High Quality Primer before Applying the Main Coat
5. Use a Range Of Waterproofing Solutions To Suit Your Property Best
6. Remove Nails Screws and Other Oxidising Metals from the Surface
7. Choose a Cooler Time of Day to Paint Your House
8. Layer, Layer, And Layer Some More!
9. Inspect Your Paint After Initial Application
10. Choose A Colour Scheme That Reflects The Character Of Your Home

[Source](http://www.joycepainting.com.au/BlogPostDetails/12/10-ways-you-can-protect-your-exterior-paintwork-and-transform-your-home)

Comment: this is a terrible answer as it doesn't actual reference the type of siding the OP is referring to.